# ImageViews inside of RelativeLayout, that is nested inside of a LinearLayout

Tags: android, layout, imageview, android-relativelayout

My goal is to display 6 images (1 image, 6 times) across one line on my screen. My approach was to nest a RelativeLayout inside of a LinearLayout. My issue is that when I'm in 'portrait' mode, I cannot see all of my images. The more I resize my image, the more of the images I can fit, But I'm at a point where I do not want it to be any smaller. I assumed that by default, it would just wrap what it can't fit, but that doesnt seem to be the case. Theres no auto re-size to fit? Also, how can I manually decide how much space is between each image? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you need to provide two different xml files for your app, one for portrait, once for landscape as per: [Providing Resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources). android will pick the proper xml file based on orientation.

and this [ImageView.ScaleType](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html) explains the different scaling styles

Here is what I would suggest:

```
res/layout-land/main.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/debris_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/image1"
    </ImageView
    ... repeat 5 more times ...
</LinearLayout>
```

the `weight` element *should* make them all fit but there might be a conflict with `scaleType`. anyway that should do it for your landscape, for portrait, you could either make it so there were two rows of images, or you could use a `horizontalScrollView` as below:

```
res/layout-port/main.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<HorizontalScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">        
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/debris_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:weight="1"
            android:padding="15dp"
            android:src="@drawable/image1"
        </ImageView
        ... repeat 5 more times ...
    </LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

really, you could prolly just use the portrait `main.xml` as your only layout file and just have it be horizontally scrolling regardless of orientation. you might need to change some times in the portrait `main.xml` as i am at work and im not sure how well `weight` works with `horizontalScrollView`

as far as the space between each element, you would use [android:padding](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android%3apadding) like i have above.